# How can I create a Bowen knot?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, workflow

The [Bowen knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowen_knot) is used on *Apple* keyboards as the symbol of the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key, also known as *Viking's Shield*, *Heraldic Knot*, etc.

I'm trying to work out the overlap. Ideally, I want to use a [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) which can then be modified in various ways using circles or planes for various end results. I guess I can use either a screw modifier or a modified spiral for the end circles, because they must either tilt up or down accordingly depending on the flow from one corner to another, right?

[image]

The flow from one corner to the next is pretty straightforward. As simple as connecting vertices. It's the end curves I'm having trouble figuring out.

How can I create a Bowen knot?

Comment: what do you mean by end curves? this shape is a bit like a Escher impossible object, so you need to find a solution, what about this: https://zupimages.net/up/20/51/r2up.jpg

Comment: so is Lemon's answer what you're looking for?

Comment: This was done using Kit Wallace's Bowen Knot code from OpenSCAD.  Saved to a minimal surface and stripping it to an edge and building from there.  It works, but, it's not Blender.

Kit Wallace's Bowen Knot (Thingiverse):

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3554009

My blend file derived from it (would've liked to attach it, but it's 168 MB! A bit big.

So, here's a photo instead.  I used a circle, a hex (six side circle), and a Bezier Curve.

Red is Hex, Blue is Curve, Green is Circle - All Bezier.

Comment: The image:  (Imgur)

https://imgur.com/a/DT7tuqw

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

From left to right:

1. Create a circle and in edit mode shift it
2. Delete a quarter of the vertices
3. Duplicate/rotate 3 times
4. Join the vertices
5. Rotate each circle (say) 10 degrees
6. Convert the mesh into a curve

[image]

Curve settings:

[image]

Give it extrusion. As the extrusion is along Z, rotate the knot around X so that it is Z up and apply the rotation.

Shader: get the U of the UV that is along the curve and add a color ramp.

### a better, quicker way

[image]

Start from a plane instead of a circle.

Add subdivisions.

Next steps are the same.

[image]

Comment: That's it!  Perfection.

Comment: For the first example I used a Bezier Curve as the Bevel object instead.  Worked just as well.

Comment: Lemon, this is the second time that I recall, this and Enneper, that you've helped me in this regard.  Thank you for your help and expertise.

A play on the results from Imgur.

https://imgur.com/a/QAR52y5